# Negative Voltage Cutoff

Tags: voltage, transistors, zener, circuit-protection, over-voltage-protection

How do I turn off a negative voltage supply using a Zener diode as well as transistors and resistors?  Let's say I have -30V supply, but I wanted it to turn off at -15V (using the zener voltage as a reference).  What kind of configuration would I need?

Comment: You want to limit it to -15V, or you want to turn it off if it goes above or below 15V...?

Comment: Turns off at -15v and anything below.

Comment: I managed to do it at a positive voltage but I can't figure out in negative supply voltage.

Comment: You should probably publish at least the schematic of the working positive switch.  Then it will be more clear what you're trying to accomplish.  Also, keep in mind that a negative voltage is basically the same as a positive one, but the positive terminal is designated as ground.

Answer (score 0):

Just invert positive side to negative.

[image]